# trouble in quoting a page from Wolfram Alpha

Tags: support, status-bydesign, hyperlinks

I wanted to put a link to Wolfram Alpha. I have plotted $(n!)^{(1/n)}$  (with parentheses included). But

> `[this page](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+%28n!%29^%281%2Fn%29)`

produces

> this page

As you see here the quoted page does not turn blue, nor is there a link.

Using the link in an address bar does give the right page though.

What is the error?

Comment: See [Carets stop hyperlinks working](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4482/carets-stop-hyperlinks-working) and other questions linked there. You could also use tinyurl or some other similar website to avoid this problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem here is the caret, i.e. the "^" symbol. The problem is that "^" is *not* a valid html symbol, and is deemed unsafe. This is not really a bug. More about that can be seen on Meta.SO: [Links with caret ^ do not work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69369/links-with-caret-do-not-work)

This does not resolve the problem you have - one possible workaround is to use ** instead of ^, which W|A interprets correctly.

> `[better](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+%28n!%29**%281%2Fn%29)`

produces

> [better](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+%28n!%29**%281%2Fn%29)

Comment: Since this is not a bug, should the tag `(bug)` be removed, so that SE developers closely watching meta.MSE (heh) can focus on real bugs? Not sure what is appropriate here.

Answer (score 6):

Another approach is to put the hyperlink in using the link tool in the editor (or <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>l</kbd>); this does something [like this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20%28n!%29%5E%281/n%29) with all the correct encoding, which is to say:

```
[like this][1]

  [1]: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20%28n!%29%5E%281/n%29
```

Answer (score 5):

The better (safer) way to embed a link with special characters is to use the "chain" icon above the answer box. It automatically applies any necessary encoding.

[Like this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20%28n!%29%5E%281/n%29)

Answer (score 0):

Look's like whatever comes after the /input/... is causing an error. For some reason it can't embed the link because of it. Changing formats for links doesn't help either.